# Jquery dynamic text value check greater than with another field value issues

Tags: jquery, validation

I have check if the value is greater than with another field value with blur method, but it's always showing invalid.

My code is :

```
var product_offer_price = jQuery('#_product_offer_price').val();
        var product_price = jQuery('#_product_price').val();
        if(product_offer_price > product_price )
        {
            alert('invalid');

        }   
        else
        {
            alert('valid'); 
        }
```

product_offer_price  : 20 
product_price  : 30

Result : Invalid

product_offer_price  : 10 
product_price  : 30

Result : Invalid

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you compare integers and not strings! You'd better make cast from strings to integers like that

```
product_offer_price = parseInt(jQuery('#_product_offer_price').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var product_offer_price = jQuery('#_product_offer_price').val();
var product_price = jQuery('#_product_price').val();

if(parseFloat(product_offer_price) > parseFloat(product_price))
    alert('invalid');
else
    alert('valid');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the input from the text area to integers.

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LcMNH/1/

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="a">
<input type="text" id="b">
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
product_offer_price = 0
product_price = 0
$("#a").blur(function (e) {
    product_offer_price = $("#a").val();
    check();
});
$("#b").blur(function (e) {
    product_price = $("#b").val();
    check();
});


function check() {
    if (product_offer_price > product_price) alert('invalid');
    else alert('valid');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please review following code, you can check working demo here :

http://jsfiddle.net/EvdNz/2/

```
$("#_product_offer_price,#_product_price").blur(function (e) {
    var product_offer_price = jQuery('#_product_offer_price').val();
    var product_price = jQuery('#_product_price').val();
    //alert(product_offer_price);
    //alert(product_price);
    if(product_offer_price > product_price )
    {
        alert('invalid');

    }   
    else
    {
        alert('valid'); 
    }
});
```

Hope this solves you problem.

Answer (score 0):

When we compare `2 text field` values using jQuery.

```
var number1 = $("#number1").val();
var number2 = $("#number2").val();
```

We should want to use `parseFloat` function.If you don't use it.you can not get real result.Because when comparing those two number Jquery can not identify those are numeric.

```
Correct use :

if(parseFloat(number1) > parseFloat(number2)){
      console.log('Highest Number is'+ number1);
} else{
      console.log('Lowest Number is'+ number2);
}
```